# none returned instead of value in list comprehension via boolean expression

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
old_list = ['bob', 'steve', 'bob', 'janice', 'jeff', 'jeff', 'marge',]
filter = []
```

### What i have tried

```
uniq_list = [filter.append(x) for x in old_list if x not in filter]
```

This puts just None results in my list. I've also tried the following but can't quite get it to work right

```
uniq_list
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

Not really sure how I could pass the actual value instead of the boolean back into the list. I've also tried something like the following.

```
uniq_list = [x for x in old_list if x not in filter]
uniq_list = [x if x not in filter for x in old_list]  # there is nothing in filter so i understand why this doesnt work
```

### What im trying to achieve

```
uniq_list
['bob', 'steve', 'janice', 'jeff', 'marge']
```

### Follow up questions

I am working my way through some dataquest courses and studying python with the new *serious python* book from no starch press as well as the *python tricks* book. I have two problems with both list comprehensions and generators:

1. how to structure a list comprehensions statement (where does the
   if go, for example) doesn't seem to be documented .. or I cant find
   it.
2. I haven't grasped or read about the concept of when you should
   use a list comprehension or generator vs just a normal for loop.

Comment: list operations are in-place and return nothing. If you want to do this right, I suggest using a loop and a set.

Comment: `list(set(old_list))` should give you the unique elements.

Comment: @coldspeed  its my understanding that list comprehensions are for creating a new list from an existing list, which is what im trying to do here. While I could do this easily with a for/if loop ... it doesnt help me get any closer to understanding and better utilizing generators and list comprehensions.

Comment: @cph_sto  Yep. Have this down as one possible solution but thank you for sharing that. Very useful.

Comment: it seems like what im trying to do is two operations from the if statement. I need the comprehension to add the output to its new list as well as add those to the filter list. 

for each item in old_list, if its not in filter add it if its unique and add it here in the new list comprehension. probably not a good approach which is why I wanted to ask.